Get BLE UUID for known BLE MAC
As I understand it there is no way of getting the BLE MAC address in iOS like there is in Android, but instead iOS creates a UUID based on the BLE MAC address that is different on different iOS devices, but the application can use it as a unique identifier in place of the BLE MAC. Source below.
My question is, can I generate such a UUID form a known BLE MAC address? That gives the option to enter the BLE MAC into the application, generate the corresponding UUID and then have the application look for a BLE advertisements with a UUID that matches. Obviously, the BLE UUID would have to not change over time for a given iOS device.
“iOS hides the MAC address of the device and generates a UUID. The UUID on iOS is generated by the iOS device. Different iOS devices will get different UUIDs for the same peripheral. The MAC address is usually based on the hardware. If we both have iPhones and scan the same peripheral, we'll see different UUIDs. iOS generates the UUID on the device and hides the MAC address.  Summary - iOS doesn't let you get the MAC address of a device, it gives you a random UUID instead.“
Source - https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/issues/77

What you call a BLE MAC is called BD_ADDR in the context of Bluetooth.
The fact that no mobile operating system today offers the option of obtaining hardware identifiers is due to the fact that user privacy is valued more highly than an application's interest in being able to uniquely identify the hardware via hardware identifiers.
So if you want to identify the hardware on which your app is running, you can read out the AdvertisingIdentifier in iOS. However, this has no relation to any hardware identifiers like MAC or BD_ADDR.
On the other hand, Apple's iOS goes a step further when it comes to the communication partners your device or application is connected to. Any hardware identification is hidden from the application by the operating system, so the hardware cannot be tracked here either.
The only way to uniquely identify a connection partner hardware via a UUID is to integrate a BLE advertising function into your application. It would then have to generate a unique 128-bit UUID, or the user would have to enter it, and the restrictions of the underlying operating system would apply.

Android allows you to see the BD_ADDR of advertising devices. There are lots a of apps (e.g. LightBlue - https://punchthrough.com/lightblue/) that allow this. You can see from the example screenshot on their website that Android version shows the ##:##:##:##:##:## BD_ADDR but iOS version doesn't. I don't want to make any connection, just observe adverts. For clarity, it's not the iOS device advertising, but third party hardware.

@user1228123 you have tagged your question with iOS, so Android doesn't matter here. If you have no control over the third-party hardware, you cannot influence what your application sees.

You may want to rework your answer to remove "no mobile operating system today offers the option of obtaining hardware identifiers." iOS is the only one I'm aware of that doesn't.

Thank you @RobNapier for your comment. Indeed, I added the second part later and understand that the whole text can be misunderstood because of that. I will correct that.


Obviously, the BLE UUID would have to not change over time for a given iOS device.

No such identifier exists. This is not possible, by design. There are various techniques that were used in the past. Apple has systematically and intentionally broken them. You will need to redesign not to require this.
A typical solution to the problem you describe is to advertise an encrypted version of your own identifier (which could be derived from the MAC/BRADDR). You shift the IV on the encryption to reduce fingerprinting. You can then look for that.
Alternately, you can connect to all "possible" devices (for example, devices that advertise the correct service) and interrogate them for their identifier.
All of this assumes you have control over the devices' firmware. If not, this isn't a solvable problem.

Bizarre, I don't know whose privacy Apple are 'protecting'. The advertising devices are 'vulnerable' to Android and other OSs and I'd argue it's not Apple's role to protect the privacy of those third party devices anyway. Apple could enact strategies with their own devices (e.g. time variant MAC/BRADDR). This just strikes me as Apple making it hard to use peripheral hardwares that haven't paid a fee to Apple.

It certainly is not about paying a fee to Apple. Getting MFi certification and including the require extra chip does not change anything about the rules. The concern is fingerprinting by apps identifying nearby devices. This is a quite real attack. I've met the people who write a library to do it; they're shockingly proud of themselves and open about how it works. You go into a bar, and one app that has GPS enabled notices a TV with a Bluetooth address and records this with the server. Another person can then be geolocated by another app that sees it even though they do not enable GPS.

You can also use a constellation of nearby Bluetooth devices to identify individual people by the devices they carry, and their interactions with other people, giving you social graphs. You see similar lock-downs from Apple in the ability of apps to determine what WiFi networks are nearby for the same reason. It has definitely been whack-a-mole, with data brokers constantly looking for new ways to fingerprint users and determine what they do. And maybe Apple is foolish to try. But it really does come from these attacks. I've paid Apple a lot to build MFi gear. It gets you almost nothing.

Useful insight, thank you. As you say it's whack-a-mole because you can think of loads of ways to do similar. Visible WiFi SSIDs (as you mentioned) would be a relatively easy one. Will all be pretty trivial in comparison to mass uptake of AR glasses though combined with face recognition. Maybe then, we can have an easier life making BLE devices as Apple will conclude that it's pointless.

"Alternately, you can connect to all "possible" devices (for example, devices that advertise the correct service) and interrogate them for their identifier." Does iOS use a temporary identifier that you can use for a session then? Having connected and established the device's BD_ADDR, I then want to just monitor advertisements from that device. I do have control of the devices firmware and of the iOS app.

If you've connected to the device, the CBPeripheral's identifier will be long-lived. They generally don't change. I've definitely seen it happen, but it's good enough for most of these uses, and you can repeat the connect/cache-identifier cycle if it ever does change. Just keep in mind that it might when designing your database.

I wouldn't expect BLE to ever be easier to track on iOS. As I mentioned, Apple removed SSID reporting as well. And I would never expect an app to be allowed to get an open-ended list of recognized faces. Always bet on things getting tighter, with very narrow exceptions made to solve enumerated use cases. This is what they've done in the past. Forbidding incoming background network connections makes VoIP basically unworkable (I used to build VoIP apps). Apple didn't just allow background network connections to fix it. They added a very specific VoIP connection type that requires an entitlement.

I presume device name and proximity is a valid, if slightly error prone, solution. What I am thinking is assuming the device of the correct name with the highest RSSI is the intended one. Or does iOS obscure device names and/or RSSI too? I'm desperate to avoid the power consumption (and firmware) overhead of making connections to the device.

Device names and RSSI are available. And of course you can place a persistent identifier in manufacturer data. I've often put one there. That's the "encrypted version of your own identifier" with a shifting IV suggestion. I generally have worked on devices that people carry with them, so I am loathe to advertise a static identifier that could be used to track my users; I want the publicly visible bytes to change over time. But especially if it is not a personal device, it would be fine to just stick a static ID (even your BRADDR) there.
